# valueformatter/getFormattedValue IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 7, Size: 7 MpAndroidChart in Barchart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am getting the following error while trying to create an horizontal barchart in valueformatter but the size of xAxis and mydatasets is same.

The strange behavior here is if size of dataset and xAxis is 8:8 then nothing goes wrong but beyond that like 7:7 it gives me exception. I have printed the dataset and xAxis arraylist both and here's the output for 7:7 ratio:

```
E/Data: [DataSet, label: NADEC, entries: 1
    Entry, x: 0.0 y: -99.8 , DataSet, label: ALMARAI, entries: 1
    Entry, x: 1.0 y: -3.7 , DataSet, label: CREME CARAMEL, entries: 1
    Entry, x: 2.0 y: -3.7 , DataSet, label: DANETTE, entries: 1
    Entry, x: 3.0 y: -2.9 , DataSet, label: AL MAZRAH, entries: 1
    Entry, x: 4.0 y: 0.0 , DataSet, label: PRIVATE LABEL, entries: 1
    Entry, x: 5.0 y: 7.8 , DataSet, label: RAWABEH, entries: 1
    Entry, x: 6.0 y: 61.5 ]
E/Brands: [NADEC, ALMARAI, CREME CARAMEL, DANETTE, AL MAZRAH, PRIVATE LABEL, RAWABEH]
```

Everything seems fine here?
and here's the setup code for horizontal bar chart:

```
private fun filterHorizontalBarData(myList: List<ResponseBrandValueGrowthChart>?) {
        try {

            val brand = ArrayList<String>()
            var index = 0f
            var color_index = 0
            val data  = BarData()

            for (item in myList!!) {
                if (item.kPI.equals("Value % Growth") || item.kPI.equals("Volume % growth")) {
                    val kpiValue = ArrayList<BarEntry>()
                    kpiValue.add(BarEntry(index,item.kPIvalue.toFloat()))
                    brand.add(item.brand)
                    val barDataSet = BarDataSet(kpiValue, item.brand)
                    if(color_index<7)
                       barDataSet.setColor(getColor(horizonatal_chart.context, getColorID(color_index)))
                    else
                        barDataSet.setColor(getColorID(color_index))
                    data.addDataSet(barDataSet)
                    index++
                    color_index++
                }
            }
           setHorizontalChart(data, brand)
        }catch (e: Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }


    private fun setHorizontalChart(data : BarData, brand: ArrayList<String>){

        Log.e("Data ",data.dataSets.toString())
        Log.e("Brands ",brand.toString())

        horizonatal_chart.setDrawBarShadow(false)
        val description = Description()
        description.text = ""
        horizonatal_chart.description = description

        horizonatal_chart.legend.setEnabled(false)
        horizonatal_chart.setPinchZoom(false)
        horizonatal_chart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false)
        horizonatal_chart.setScaleEnabled(false)
        horizonatal_chart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true)

        //Display the axis on the left (contains the labels 1*, 2* and so on)
        val xAxis = horizonatal_chart.getXAxis()
        xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false)
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM)
        xAxis.setEnabled(true)
        xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false)
        xAxis.textColor = Color.parseColor("#a1a1a1")

        val yLeft = horizonatal_chart.axisLeft

        //Set the minimum and maximum bar lengths as per the values that they represent
        yLeft.axisMaximum = 100f
        yLeft.axisMinimum = 0f
        yLeft.isEnabled = false

        //Now add the labels to be added on the vertical axis
        xAxis.valueFormatter = IAxisValueFormatter { value, axis -> brand[value.toInt()] }

        val yRight = horizonatal_chart.axisRight
        yRight.setDrawAxisLine(true)
        yRight.setDrawGridLines(false)
        yRight.isEnabled = false

        //Set bar entries and add necessary formatting
        horizonatal_chart.axisLeft.setAxisMinimum(data.yMin)

        data.barWidth = 0.9f
//        val myCustomChartRender = MyCustomChartRender(horizonatal_chart, horizonatal_chart.animator, horizonatal_chart.viewPortHandler)
//        //Add animation to the graph
//        horizonatal_chart.renderer = myCustomChartRender
        horizonatal_chart.animateY(2000)
        horizonatal_chart.data = data
        horizonatal_chart.setTouchEnabled(false)
        horizonatal_chart.invalidate()
    }
```

Is there anything wrong with this code? and why it is working with size 8 of both mydata and labels?
Please help me out!!!

Update:
**Exception stacktrace**:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 7, Size: 7
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
        at com.almaraiquest.almarai.GrowthStoryFragment$setHorizontalChart$1.getFormattedValue(GrowthStoryFragment.kt:321)
        at com.github.mikephil.charting.components.AxisBase.getFormattedLabel(AxisBase.java:489)
        at com.github.mikephil.charting.components.AxisBase.getLongestLabel(AxisBase.java:475)
        at com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.XAxisRendererHorizontalBarChart.computeSize(XAxisRendererHorizontalBarChart.java:67)
        at com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.XAxisRenderer.computeAxisValues(XAxisRenderer.java:74)
        at com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.XAxisRendererHorizontalBarChart.computeAxis(XAxisRendererHorizontalBarChart.java:58)
        at com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarLineChartBase.onDraw(BarLineChartBase.java:209)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17071)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16053)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3734)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16016)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3734)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16016)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3734)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16016)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3734)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16016)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3734)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16016)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3734)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16016)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3734)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16016)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3734)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16016)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3734)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16016)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3734)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16016)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3734)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16016)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:656)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:662)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:770)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2828)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2636)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2243)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1278)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6357)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
2019-12-24 07:46:31.169 26673-26673/com.almaraiquest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: It happened once setting data with 8 size, then updating data to 5 items. I had to call `.clear()` before updating

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/3253 Unfortunately the issue is still open, even after 2 years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got my solution finally:

```
 xAxis.valueFormatter = IAxisValueFormatter { value, axis ->
                if (value.toInt() < brand.size) {
                    brand.get(value.toInt())
                } else {
                    "0"
                }
            }
```

Source: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/3253

Answer (score 0):

IAxisValueFormatter is deprecated now you can use ValueFormatter.

```
inner class MyXAxisValueFormatter(private val values : ArrayList<String>) : ValueFormatter() {

        override fun getFormattedValue(value : Float) : String {
            return if (value.toInt() < values.size && value.toInt() >= 0) values[value.toInt()] else "0"
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution based on the answer before.
**JAVA CODE:**

```
 private void initSecGraph() {

 // .....Other stuff.....
        
        final ArrayList<String> x = measurements.getLastMeasurementsDurationsDates_ByLastDays(7);
       
        ValueFormatter formatter = new ValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
                if(((int)value) < x.size())
                return x.get((int) value) ;
                else
                    return "0";
            }
        };       
            xAxis.setValueFormatter(formatter);

           // .....Other stuff.....
    }
```